The rank of a matrix made by the diagonal components of the matrix exponential
I define the $4 \times 4$ matrix $K$ as
$$K=\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\log{p} & a & 0 & 0 \\
a & \log{q} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \log{cp} & a \\
0 & 0 & a & \log{cq} \\
\end{bmatrix}\right),$$
where $a$, $c$, $p$ and $q$ are real numbers. I also define $2 \times 2$ matrix $U$ as
$$U=\begin{bmatrix}
K_{11} & K_{33}  \\
K_{22} & K_{44}  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
As I see in numerical simulation, the matrix rank of $U$ seem to be always $1$. But I cannot prove it mathematically. How can I do that?

I've finished to write my answer now, you may take a look ;)

thanks. It made sense to me.

The matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} X & 0 \\ 0 & Y \end{bmatrix},
\text{ where }
X = \begin{bmatrix} \log p & a \\ a & \log q \end{bmatrix}
\text{and }
Y = \log c + X,
$$
is block-diagonal, hence
$$
K = e^M 
  = \begin{bmatrix} e^X & 0 \\ 0 &  e^Y \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} e^X & 0 \\ 0 & ce^X \end{bmatrix},
$$
given that $\log c$ and $X$ commute, and finally
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix} K_{11} & K_{33} \\ K_{22} & K_{44} \end{bmatrix} 
  = \begin{bmatrix} K_{11} & cK_{22} \\ K_{22} & cK_{11} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $U$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, we may study its rank through its eigenvalues, which themselves can be determineed with the help of the determinant and the trace of $U$, since the rank corresponds to the space dimension minus the number of eigenvalues equal to zero. If we denote the eigenvalues of $U$ by $\lambda_\pm$, then we have :
$$
\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{tr}U \pm \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}^2U - 4\det U}\right),
$$
with
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
   \operatorname{tr}U &= (1+c)K_{11} \\
   \det U             &= c(K_{11}^2-K_{22}^2)
\end{align}
\right.
$$
A zero rank would require $K_{11} = K_{22} = 0$, which is impossible, because it would imply $\operatorname{tr}e^X = K_{11} + K_{22} = 0$, while $e^{X}$ must have strictly positive eigenvalues.
The matrix $U$ may have rank 1, as you observed. It occurs when $K_{11} = K_{22}$, which itself is possible when $p = q$ by symmetry for example, since
$$
e^X = e^p \begin{bmatrix} \cosh a & \sinh a \\ \sinh a & \cosh a \end{bmatrix}
$$
in that case. Other cases are certainly possible, where $a$ "compensates" the fact that $p \neq q$ in order to ensure $K_{11} = K_{22}$.
But $U$ has full rank if $K_{11} \neq K_{22}$, when $p \neq q$ and $a = 0$ for instance.
